# Performance when matching on strings

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have a chat application and I want to avoid the same message being inserted more than once.

In this case I can upsert based on the `message_text` field, but are there any performance tradeoffs when using string or text columns in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: an index on `message_text` column would obviously help.

Comment: Note that Unicode collation can slow down your index lookups dramatically. You might want to declare your column as `COLLATE "C"`.

Answer (score 0):

String comparison is of course slower than Integer. But In your case I think there is no other way.